_CompactIterable<String> is not a subtype of type 'String'
I saved some values in a List of Map values.
List<Map<String, String>> savedValues = [];

Now, I want to extract those values and keys in a List. I want to extract them as a String. When I try to do this and try to show these values in ListView.builder(), I am getting the error as mentioned above.
I am doing this.
    List _values = [];
    List _keys = [];

    for (var value in savedValues) 
       {
         _values.add(value.values);
         _keys.add(value.keys);
       }

I tried different solutions but did not understand, how to do it. Any help, please?

You need to learn to use proper typing, so your compiler can tell you where you made a mistake.
Your lists are untyped, which means they are lists of something. When you add to your lists, you add sets of values as a whole. So you don't fill strings into a list of strings, you fill "bunches of strings" into a list of somethings, that obviously was meant as a list of "bunches of strings". Well, it wasn't meant that way. Lets try this with proper types:
final _values = <String>[];
final _keys = <String>[];

for (var value in savedValues) 
{
  _values.addAll(value.values);
  _keys.addAll(value.keys);
}

With proper types, your line of "add" instead of "addAll" would have brought up a compile errors for you, informing you that "add" does not do what you think it does.
